# decoding array of utf8 strings inside a stream

Tags: javascript, utf-8

I faced a weird problem today after trying to decode a utf8 formatted string. It's being fetched through stream as an array of strings but formatted in utf8 somehow (I'm using [fast-csv](https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv)). However as you can see in the console if I log it directly it shows the correct version but when it's inside an object literal it's back to utf8 encoded version.

```
  var stream = fs
    .createReadStream(__dirname + '/my.csv')
    .pipe(csv({ ignoreEmpty: true }))
    .on('data', data => {
        console.log(data[0])
        // prints farren@rogers.com
        console.log({ firstName: data[0] })
        // prints { firstName: '\u0000f\u0000a\u0000r\u0000r\u0000e\u0000n\u0000@\u0000r\u0000o\u0000g\u0000e\u0000r\u0000s\u0000.\u0000c\u0000o\u0000m\u0000' }
    })
```

Any solution or explanations are appreciated.

Edit: even after decoding using [utf8.js](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/utf8.js) and then pass it in the object literal, I still encounter the same problem.

Comment: Given the NUL characters interleaved in the output, it seems like the input might be UTF-16 being read as UTF-8. Ask the author of the CSV file which encoding they chose (or ask for an xlsx instead-they are much more self-describing).

Comment: @TomBlodget oh my god, I can't believe I didn't check that already. I though it was utf8 all this time, since it was exported from google contacts. You can answer this question and I'll mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: @TomBlodget btw what do you mean by `NUL characters interleaved` and how can I self study about these stuff? Did you see an special character that you figured it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript uses UTF-16 for Strings. It also has a numeric escape notation for a UTF-16 code unit. So, when you see this output in your debugger

```
\u0000f\u0000a\u0000r\u0000r\u0000e\u0000n
```

It is saying that the String's code units are \u0000 f \u0000 a etc. The \uHHHH escape means the UTF-16 code unit HHHH in hexadecimal. \u0000 is the single (unpaired) UTF-16 code unit need for the U+0000 (NUL) Unicode codepoint. So, something is being interpreted as NUL f NUL a, etc.

UTF-8 code units are 8 bits each. NUL in UTF-8 is 0x00. f is 0x66.

UTF-16 code units are 16 bits each. NULL is 0x0000. f is 0x0066. When 16-bit values are stored as bytes, endianness applies. In little endian, 0x0066 is written as 0x66 0x00. In big endian, 0x00 0x66.

So, if bytes of UTF-16 code units (such as the ones in the example data) are interpreted as UTF-8 (or perhaps other encodings), f can be read as NUL f or f NUL.

**The fundamental rule of character encodings is to read with the same encoding that text was written with.** No doing so can lead to data loss and corruption that can go on undetected. Not knowing what the encoding is to begin with is data loss itself and a failed communication.

You can learn more about Unicode at [Unicode.org](https://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html). You can learn more about languages and technologies that use it from their respective specifications—they are all very upfront and clear about it. [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt), Java, C#, VBA/VB4/VB5/VB6, VB.NET, F#, HTML, XML, T-SQL,…. (Okay, VB4 documentation might not be quite as clear but the point is that this is very common and not new [[VBPJ Sept. 1996](http://vb.mvps.org/articles/pt199609.pdf)], though we all are still struggling to assimilate it.)

Comment: I exported the csv file via google contacts and had no idea it's UTF-16. After reading your answer I opened it in VSC instead of Vim and saw it's actually UTF-16, changed it to utf-8 and everything started working again